# How do I get `Data` objects into Swift-NIO without making copies?

Tags: swift, macos, foundation, swift-nio, soto

I'm fairly new to Swift and *very* new to NIO.

I'm adding Swift code to a large project that needs to up/down load a lot of data (GBs) to AWS. To that end, I've imported the GitHub project [Soto](https://github.com/soto-project/soto), which relies heavily on NIO.

Most methods that send/receive data do so through `ByteBuffer` structs. My application already has the data to upload in Foundation `Data` objects. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to get these `Data` objects into NIO.

In the documentation for [NIO's `ByteBuffer` (2.26.0)](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Structs/ByteBuffer.html#) it states

*Supported types:
A variety of types can be read/written from/to a ByteBuffer. ... Out of the box, ByteBuffer supports for example the following types (non-exhaustive list):*

- *String/StaticString*
- *Swift’s various (unsigned) integer types*
- ***Foundation‘s Data***
- *[UInt8] and generally any Collection of UInt8*

However, the latest swift-nil package has no `ByteBuffer` support for Foundation `Data` objects. Instead, it supports `DispatchData` objects, which in turn seem to have no interoperability with `Data` objects.

What I want to avoid is making a copy of every block of data (100's of MB at a time), just to convert between `Data` and `DispatchData` types.

So...

Right now my thinking is one of

- I'm completely lost, and there's a simple solution I haven't found
- The solution is to create a subclass of `DispatchData` backed by a `Data` object
- Initialize the `ByteBuffer` structure using a `DispatchData` created using the no-copy initializer pointing to the raw byte array in the `Data` object, along with a custom deallocator that simply retains the `Data` object until the `ByteBuffer` and `DispatchData` objects are destroyed.

I would appreciate any thoughts, experience, or suggestions (particularly if it's option #1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `import NIOFoundationCompat` to get any of NIO's method that work with `Foundation` data types such as `Data` (or `JSONDecoder`/`JSONEncoder`). `NIOFoundationCompat` is just another module of the `swift-nio` package so you won't need another dependency.

But just to be clear, under the hood, there will always be copies but probably you don't need to worry about them, copies are extremely fast on today's CPUs. If you absolutely want to avoid copies, you'll need to create `ByteBuffer`s straight away. To help you with that, you may want to add where you get your data from that you want to send over the network.

Comment: Thanks, Johannes! I knew the answer was #1. ;) On an aside, I wasn't worried about speed as much as memory usage. I could have as many as 4 upload operations running simultaneously, each holding on to as much as 256 MB of data in Data objects. Having to duplicate them all means there could be a GB of RAM that's nothing more than a copy of another GB of RAM. That seems excessive to me. I'll look into refactoring my code to see if I can create the ByteBuffers earlier—and discard the Data objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about memory usage and are uploading large buffers perhaps you should be using `AWSPayload.stream`. This allows you to stream small `ByteBuffers` to AWS. Here is an example of streaming `Data` to S3 in 16k chunks

```swift
func uploadData( _ data: Data) -> EventLoopFuture<S3.PutObjectOutput> {
    var index = 0
    let payload = AWSPayload.stream { eventLoop in
        let maxChunkSize = 16*1024
        let size = min(maxChunkSize, data.count - index)
        // are we done yet
        if size == 0 {
            return eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(.end)
        } else {
            // create bytebuffer and return
            let byteBuffer = ByteBufferAllocator().buffer(data: data[index..<(index+size)])
            index += size
            return eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(.byteBuffer(byteBuffer))
        }
    }
    let putRequest = S3.PutObjectRequest(body: payload, bucket: name, key: "tempfile")
    return s3.putObject(putRequest)
}
```

Comment: I guess great minds think alike! I actually ended up using a stream. I decided to do the conversion on the front end: My individual `Data` buffers get converted into a FIFO of ByteBuffers (allowing me to release the `Data` objects early and merge tiny blocks). At delivery time, the only thing my payload stream block has to do is `return popBuffer()`.